# Using text-overflow: ellipsis with flexbox

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm building a shopping cart page and want to list products' image, title, price, and a form element to remove it from the cart.

I've tried using `white-space: nowrap;`, `overflow: hidden;`, and `text-overflow: ellipsis;` together on elements that I want to truncate, but I can't figure out how to display them correctly, especially with `img-container` and `name-price-container` using flexbox.

Here's my Django template:

```html
<ul>
    {% for product in products %}
    <li class="row product">
        <div class="img-container">
            <a href="{% url 'gallery:product_page' %}?id={{ product.id }}">
                <img src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="{{ product.name }}">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="name-price-container">
            <span>
                <a href="{% url 'gallery:product_page' %}?id={{ product.id }}">{{ product.name }} Loooooooooong Text</a>
            </span>
            <span>${{ product.price_per_unit }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-container">
            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'gallery:remove_cart' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.id }}">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-light" value="Remove">
            </form>
        </div>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

...and the relevant CSS:

```css
.product .img-container {
  background-color: #343a40;
  border: 1px solid #343a40;
  box-sizing: unset;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.product .img-container img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 128px;
  max-width: 128px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.name-price-container {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 0;
}
.name-price-container a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.btn-container {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.btn-container .btn {
  margin: 0;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  body * {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .product .img-container {
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
  }
  .product .img-container img {
    max-width: 64px;
    max-height: 64px;
  }
}
```

...and the rendering at 470px width:
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXBz0.png)

Notice that the first and third results render correctly, but if the text is longer than what fits on the page, instead of being truncated, the form element breaks to a new line.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** Here's the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mr1p2w3t) as per Andrei's comment.

Comment: *"The relevant CSS"* means that [this](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/b5q7mxsr/) renders the same as your image. You're not close to relevant, yet. Please provide a [mcve]. Your question can easily be answered if you provide HTML and CSS alone, since it's strictly a style related question. Hint: right-click and select "View page source" to copy/paste the relevant HTML from your app and update your CSS with enough to render the elements as in your application. You can also add external resources from cdn.

Comment: Check the edit for an updated example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several changes you need to make in order to obtain the desired behavior. First of all, you need to understand you're dealing with a negative space scenario in flexbox. That's when the sum of lengths of contents is bigger than the available parent length.
In this case, flexbox calculates the difference between them and tries to distribute the difference evenly between children which allow `flex-shrink`, according to each child's `flex-shrink` factor.

So you need to set `.name-price-container`'s `flex-shrink` to `1`:

```
 .name-price-container {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
 }
```

Without it, ellipsis won't happen, as the contents (your `<a>`) will always grow as much as they need to and thus set the `width`, hence the `flex-basis`, of `.name-price-container` (which can't currently shrink). Hence, no ellipsis.

---

Your second problem is with the fact `<a>` elements, by default have a `display` of `inline`. In order to make ellipsis work you need a method to limit its width. The simplest would be to give it `display:block` (because now the parent is shrunk). An alternative would be to move the ellipsis effect to the `span` and give that span `width: 100%`.

Finally, you want to prevent `.btn-container` from shrinking and remove its `overflow`. Give it `flex-shrink: 0` and remove `overflow: hidden` from it.

By the way, `body * { overflow: hidden; }` is ***really*** something you want to avoid, as it overrides the default value of `overflow` for every single element in your page. There are a lot of elements which will no longer work as expected if you change that. Dropdowns, tooltips, popovers and modals, to name a few.

Here's your working example:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
body {
  background-color: #e6ebf0;
}
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li img {
  width: 100%;
}
.img-container {
  background-color: #343a40;
  border: 1px solid #343a40;
 display: flex;
 flex: 1 0 auto;
 flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
form {
  display: inline;
}
.btn-light {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
}
.row {
  margin: 0;
}
.product {
  display: flex;
}
.product,
.total {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.product .img-container {
  background-color: #343a40;
  border: 1px solid #343a40;
  box-sizing: unset;
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.product .img-container img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 128px;
  max-width: 128px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.name-price-container {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 0;
}
.name-price-container a {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.name-price-container a,
.name-price-container a:hover {
  color: #212529;
}
.btn-container {
  height: 130px;
  line-height: 130px;
  min-width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.btn-container .btn {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .product .img-container {
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
  }
  .product .img-container img {
    max-width: 64px;
    max-height: 64px;
  }
  .btn-container {
    height: 66px;
    line-height: 66px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        
        <li class="row product">
            <div class="img-container">
                <a href="/gallery/product?id=21">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CyYN9a7.jpg" alt="Vials">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="name-price-container">
                <span>
                    <a href="/gallery/product?id=21">Vials Loooooooooong Text</a>
                </span>
                <span>$30.00</span>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-container">
                <form method="POST" action="/gallery/remove_cart">
                    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="...">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="21">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-light" value="Remove">
                </form>
            </div>
        </li>
        
        <li class="row product">
            <div class="img-container">
                <a href="/gallery/product?id=22">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/PoCaEjw.jpg" alt="Driftbird">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="name-price-container">
                <span>
                    <a href="/gallery/product?id=22">Driftbird Loooooooooong Text</a>
                </span>
                <span>$25.00</span>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-container">
                <form method="POST" action="/gallery/remove_cart">
                    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="...">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="22">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-light" value="Remove">
                </form>
            </div>
        </li>
        
        <li class="row product">
            <div class="img-container">
                <a href="/gallery/product?id=19">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KxAyAyE.jpg" alt="Dragon">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="name-price-container">
                <span>
                    <a href="/gallery/product?id=19">Dragon Loooooooooong Text</a>
                </span>
                <span>$300.00</span>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-container">
                <form method="POST" action="/gallery/remove_cart">
                    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="...">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="19">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-light" value="Remove">
                </form>
            </div>
        </li>
        
    </ul>
</div>
```

Updated [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/b5q7mxsr/1/)

Comment: Thanks Andrei, the updated fiddle you posted behaves exactly as I intended. There is, however, a problem using this with Bootstrap's `row` class. I found that the class as I originally included disrupts the truncating behavior, but removing it solved the issue.

Comment: To make the truncation work, `name-price-container` also needs `min-width: 0`. This was already set in the question, but otherwise the div will have a min-width of auto, which prevents it from shrinking.

Answer (score 0):

I know that your question mentioned flexbox specifically, but I would use `display: grid` for this case. [Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) will allow you to define the columns more accurately, maintain space between each section of content in the row, and truncate that content within the grid area.

This will also keep you from needing to use float along with flexbox, which can have unintended consequences. Because it keeps content well-defined within rows and columns at any size, grid is the most appropriate display option for what you're doing here.

It could look something like this:

```
.product { //each .product container will contain 1 row with 3 columns
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem; //this adds a gap between the sections of your row
  grid-template: "image info button" 128px / 128px auto 128px; //i assumed your button is 128px wide
}

.product .img-container {
  background-color: #343a40;
  border: 1px solid #343a40;
  box-sizing: unset;
  grid-area: image; //this places the .img-container div within the "image" grid area defined above in grid-template
  height: 128px;
  width: 128px;
}
.product .img-container img {
  display: block;
  max-height: 128px;
  max-width: 128px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
.name-price-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  grid-area: info; //this places the .img-container div within the "info" grid area
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 0;
}
.name-price-container span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.btn-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  grid-area: button; //this places the .img-container div within the "button" grid area
  justify-content: center;
}
.btn-container .btn {
  margin: 0;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  body * {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .product {
    grid-template: "image info button" 64px / 64px auto 128px;
  }
  .product .img-container {
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
  }
  .product .img-container img {
    max-width: 64px;
    max-height: 64px;
  }
}
```

See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/jaredgorski/pen/GzoXvY) for an example of this in action.

There is a way to do what you're trying to do with flexbox, but it's not as easy to maintain. If you take the time to translate this to grid, you'll have a more reliable layout. If you try this code out, you'll find that the

Please note that <=IE11 doesn't fully support grid, though you may not need to support IE11 or lower. If you do, there are special tricks for implementing grid layouts by using the `-ms` vendor prefix. [Here](https://medium.com/@elad/supporting-css-grid-in-internet-explorer-b38669e75d66) is a great article detailing some tricks you can use (and a module that will automatically convert your CSS to be IE11 compatible).

I hope this helps!

Comment: This is great, except it doesn't truncate text like I asked.

Comment: @user2858094 - My apologies, just added the truncation. You'll just want to add the truncation styles to the span wrapping the anchor and not the anchor itself, and then add `min-width: 0` to the container to the .name-price-container (like in flexbox). Let me know if you run into issues!

Comment: I ended up sticking with flexbox in this case since Andrei posted a simple solution that didn't involve refactoring my code, but the CSS Tricks link you posted will be very helpful moving forward, thank you.

Comment: Andrei had an excellent solution that taught me a lot about flexbox. Glad he could help you!